# Whats the best way: Slicing or pure code?

Tags: design, photoshop

I had a designer code me a website about games by designing it in photohsop then slicing it up. Not even sure what the term "slicing" means, but I can sort of give it a guess. Im learning to code myself now though, and need advice. Should I go into this with pure knowledge of code, and stick to notepad? Or start in Photoshop, then learn how to slice, and continue that way.

To make this simple. A) To slice? or B) to code?

Comment: I have always been rather suspicious of those who code primarily using Adobe products. The reason has something to do with those I met who focus in coding using these tools and not the tools. I use notepad for all the code I write. I only cheat somewhat by using a CAD for my schema and some other more complicated activities. But still, I prefer to code the good ole fashioned way- mostly because that is how I started and I do not need much else. You know- using a mallet and stone chisels with grog and pog which are even more old school than I am. They use their foreheads!

Comment: Glad to hear comments on this so quickly. Stack is the max!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To code!  I think you will have greater flexibility if you utilize html/CSS and then use images only when necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I guess theres no need to start a new quesiton. But...Whats the best application for editing code? I use Notepadd ++ on Windows 8 at the moment

Comment: I enjoy notepad++ and also sublime text 2.  I think you would enjoy www.codepen.io too.  It's free to make an account and you can enter your html, and CSS on the same screen and it instantly shows you the results.  A lot of people use it as a sort of sandbox to test ideas and develop pieces or entire websites even!

Comment: @NickBlack One code editor I thought enough to install then ignore [5hi7 3@71ng gr1n] is Komodo IDE found here: http://komodoide.com/ I still use notepad. That was an upgrade from what I was using before. Not sure what this new fangled ++ thing is all about. But Komodo IDE does look pretty good and I trust ActiveState.